# Which algorithms can be used to measure similarity for two very different languages?

Tags: machine-learning, edit-distance

recently I have read this paper, [A Survey of text similarity approaches](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5b5c/a878c534aee3882a038ef9e82f46e102131b.pdf), and I discovered that there are a lot of algorithms that can be used to measure similarity.

At present I am applying the method of soft similarity (link to the paper: [Soft similarity and soft cosine](http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/cys/v18n3/v18n3a7.pdf)):

> "Our idea is more general: we propose to modify the
>   manner of calculation of similarity in Vector Space Model
>   taking into account similarity of features. If we apply
>   this idea to the cosine measure, then the “soft cosine
>   measure” is introduced, as opposed to traditional “hard
>   cosine”, which ignores similarity of features. Note that
>   when we consider similarity of each pair of features, it
>   is equivalent to introducing new features in the VSM.
>   Essentially, we have a matrix of similarity between pairs
>   of features and all these features represent new dimensions in the VSM. [...] **The next question is how to measure similarity between features**. In general, the measuring of similarity
>   depends on the nature of the features. In our case,
>   we compare features using the Levenshtein distance [6],
>   taking advantage of the fact that they are usually strings
>   in case of natural language processing"

I am working on vectors trying to align Language1 and the same language in leet form. My question here is: are there any other distance measures that I can test a part from the here mentioned Levenshtein distance and the cosine distance? and why should I prefer one from another?